# Binding a select-list's value

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I have a setup very similar to the following jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/EM9Rh/72/
In my implementation I am using the mapping plugin to map my MVC Model to a JS Model for binding.

**Implementation: Select-Binding**

```
<span data-bind="with: Value">
     <select data-bind="options: DropDown.Options, optionsValue: $data, optionsText: 'Name', value: Selected"></select>
</span>
```

**Question(s):**

How do I map the value of a select-list (like the one above) to one of the options?
*Notice my JSON object in the JSFiddle, How do I map it so that the select starts with option '3' selected?*

How do I map the value of a select-list in the JSFiddle? (Asking both encase it differs due to use of the mapping-plugin).

I've read both the documentation for option/select-binding and the mapping plugin but I just can't seem to get it to work. I've tried `data-bind=".....value: Selected"` but it never sets and actually messes what does work up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to set the value of selected to the object that you want selected:

```
SetSelectToItem: function(item) {
   this.Value.Selected(this.Value.DropDown.Options[item-1]);   
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cz5K7/)

Note that object equality requires you set it to the object itself, not an identical object. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21446178/setting-select-list-value-in-knockout-js/21446359#21446359) for details on that.